# What's the use and impacts of calendar.js in mage 1.9.x

Tags: layout, product-view, ce-1.9.2.2, calendar

We are using CE 1.9.2.2 currently and I am desperate to get rid of the `calendar.js`-es and `.css`-es in my layout file. I'm not sure what they are used for but all I see is a large bloat of unnecessary inline-scripting and JS and CSS loading.

But as soon as I comment out one of the following lines in my (custom) `catalog.xml`, the whole product single view breaks and fall back to an undefined layout-file (somehow a CSS newsfeed is shown in the sidebar).

```
[...]
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
[...]
  <reference name="head">
    <action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><name>calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css</name><params/>
    <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar.js</name>
    <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar-setup.js</name>
  </reference>
[...]
  <reference name="content">
    <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
      [...]
      <block type="core/html_calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="page/js/calendar.phtml"/>
      </block>
      [...]
    </block>
  </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

So far I cannot tell what these three files do and where we would need them. But I can't throw them out either. Why is commenting out the JS and CSS as well as the `html_calendar`-block destroying the overall layout for `<catalog_product_view>`? Even more: the catalog_category pages only show the (correctly populated) layred navigation, but not products...